# Query with Events was happening in march, 2007

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve this problem. But I have difficult working with dates, dates overlapping, whatever.

I would like to get all events that was happening in March, 2007.

My events table:

- ID
- name
- start_date
- end_date

I am trying:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE (MONTH(start_date)<=3 AND
       YEAR(start_date)<=2007) AND (YEAR(end_date)>=2007 AND
       MONTH(end_date)>=3)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The second and looks clearly wrong. As you are comparing month with 2007.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you’re using

Comment: "i have difficult" conveys very little information about the observed  behavior. Is an error being returned? Is the query hanging and never finishing? Is it returning a resultset that is unexpected? Rows are missing, or too many rows. Very important in asking about SQL queries is the *datatypes* of the referenced columns. "Can you help me?" also does not give much useful information about the problem. Consider providing example data and expected output as a way of clarifying the specification, and asking an actual question.

Comment: Can you detail what is going wrong?  I'm assuming you are not seeing some events that you were expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you would use:

```
where start_date < '2007-04-01' and end_date >= '2007-03-01'
```

This will give any event active during the month.

If you want events that are *only* in the month, then:

```
where start_date >= '2007-03-01' and end_date < '2007-04-01'
```

Comment: +10 This assumes that start_date and end_date columns are DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP datatype. This form also "works" for string types that are stored starting with canonical ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` (such that string comparisons are equivalent to date comparisons.) Predicates on *bare* columns allow for MySQL to make use of range scan operation on suitable index (performance advantage) vs wrapping columns in functions which prevents MySQL from making effective use of indexes.